# JavaScript + Format duration with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have some JavaScript running in Node. This code dynamically gets a number of seconds. For the sake of this example, I'll choose 180 to represent 3 minutes. I'm trying to format the number of seconds like "3:00" using Moment.js. I'm trying to format the number of seconds using the [Moment duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) and [Moment duration format plugin](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format). My code looks like this:

```
var duration = 180; 
var text = moment.duration(duration, 'seconds').format('mm:ss'); 
console.log(text);
```

When I run this, I see `text` is printed as `00`. It's not formatted as I'd expect and I do not understand why. Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue, I get `03:00` using your code.

Comment: @VincenzoC Thank you for your response. I just found the issue. `duration` is being passed in as a string instead of a number in my actual code.